# Extracting values from list based on their type?

Tags: haskell, types

Im trying to iterate over a list of custom data types, and exact the value of a specific type. In this case, I want the **ages** from the list:

```
data MyData = Age Int | DOB Int | Name String | Address String

myList = [Age 89, DOB 13, Age 33, Name "Barbra", Address "103 Lane"]

myFunction :: [MyData] -> MyData
myFunction (x : xs) = if x == Age then x : myFunction xs else myFunction xs
```

Error:

```
"Age is applied to too few arguments"
```

Whats the best solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really have `x == Age` ... that doesn't make sense.  You can only compare `x` to other values of type `MyData`, like `Age 10`, or `DOB 40`, or `Name "John"`.  `Age` doesn't have type `MyData` ... it has type `Int -> MyData`.

You can check what constructor a value has by using case statements:

```
myFunction :: [MyData] -> MyData
myFunction (x:xs) = case x of
                      Age _     -> ...
                      DOB _     -> ...
                      Name _    -> ...
                      Address _ -> ...
```

Or if you only care about the `Age` constructor, you can wildcard everything else:

```
myFunction :: [MyData] -> MyData
myFunction (x:xs) = case x of
                      Age _ -> ...
                      _     -> ...
```

Also note that you might actually be wanting to return a `[MyData]`, not a `MyData`.

For what it's worth, a nicer way to write this function might be

```
myFunction :: [MyData] -> [MyData]
myFunction xs = [ x | x@(Age _) <- xs ]
```

Or you can use a higher order function instead of explicit recursion, which tends to be more prone to bugs:

```
myFunction :: [MyData] -> [MyData]
myFunction = mapMaybe (\x -> case x of Age _ -> Just x; _ -> Nothing)
```

**EDIT**: Be careful of the language you're using here in the question -- all values of `x` have the *same* type, here -- `MyData`.  `Age 10` has the same type as `DOB 40`.  They are all values of the same type, just created using different constructors.  So this isn't filtering a list for values of a certain type -- it's filtering it for values created by a certain constructor.

Comment: In an imperative lang, like c++, some compilers would interpret 'x == Age' as 'x is of type Age', thats the madness behind the method..

Comment: I don't quite think that that's a property of imperative languages :o  That's just how the language treats `==`, but it's not a particularly imperative thing. could be just as likely in a functional language :)

Comment: Also, remember that `x` is never "of type `Age`", here, because `Age` is not a type.  `x` is always of type `MyData`.

Comment: Thank you, helpful answer! Also, your blog looks interesting :)

Comment: Your statement about C++ is wrong ... That doesn't work that way in C++ either